# ¿Como cambiar el numero de filas que se muestran de un recurso?

Tags: laravel

Cuando un recurso tiene un campo tipo `Relationship`, en especial el campo BelongsToMany, siempre se visualiza una lista de los modelos asociados. Esa lista siempre tiene 5 elementos y sus respectivos botones de "Previous" y "Next".

Por ejemplo, si tengo un recurso de `Client` y una relacion a otro recurso `Product`,

¿Como puedo cambiar el numero de filas de productos que se muestran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por alguna extraña razon, esta propiedad no esta documentada en Laravel Nova. Para lograr mostrar un numero mayor de filas, es necesario usar la siguiente propiedad en el recurso de `Product`

```
public static $perPageViaRelationship = 15;
```

De esta forma, al consultar los productos asociados al cliente, se mostraran los primeros 15, en vez de los primeros 5. Es importante recalcar que esta configuracion solo funciona cuando el recurso es consultado en a traves de una relacion y uno funciona en la vista Index.

El unico lugar donde he podido encontrar esta informacion es en un [issue de Github](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/72), en uno de los comentarios.